# JetBrains products not showing FN keys on touchbar

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have a Macbook with touchbar and wanted to set touchbar to always show FN keys for JetBrains apps. I have done it in preferences, same as for other apps. FN keys shows as default in those apps when they are in focus but not in the JetBrains apps.

Comment: How do you install JetBrains products? If it's via ToolBox -- maybe check comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167332

Comment: yeah, that resolved the issue, needed to select Idea from ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/ the problem I see is that I would need to do this after every update :/ Can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept? @LazyOne

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using ToolBox App to install your JetBrains products then please have a look at the comments in [IDEA-167332](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167332) ticket -- you will have to locate your apps in `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/` folder.

Downside -- you need to repeat this to every new build of such app that you will install as the path to actual app will be different every time.

---

**UPDATE:** the aforementioned ticket has been marked as fixed for **2018.2.x version** version. You now have an option on `Preferences | Keymap` screen.

Answer (score 12):

By default it is not possible to select inside of an app folder. So in order to be able to get the function keys configured, follow the following steps:

go to:
System preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Functions keys

Click the + icon

Then press CMD+SHIFT+G to open up a path window. Enter: ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps

Select the correct application and version to make the function keys work again.

Repeat for every application you use.

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to list the simplest way I've found. It is based on [Rob's related, helpful answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44667653), but I've tried to make it simpler and clearer, without unnecessary steps.

- Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts (tab).
- Click "Functions Keys" from the pane on the left.
- Click "+". A file picker will pop up.
- Select your application; e.g. `CLion` or `IntelliJ`.

That's it. Now, when you open up your application, you will see function keys in the touch bar.

[image: macOS > System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts]

Comment: simple and straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

JetBrains has implementation in IDE preferences to fix this. Open your IDE and go to

**Preferences** (⌘-,) > **Keymap**

Then check "Always show function keys (F1-F12) on the Touch Bar."

Restart the IDE and you should see function keys.

[image: Keymap]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Setting the fn keys using apple's keyboard settings using doesn't work for apps installed using the JetBrains Toolbox, even if I set the correct app in the `Toolbox` folder.

Comment: This seems broken in Clion 2019.3 EAP unfortunately.

Comment: @dvdplm Sometimes you need to fiddle around with it a little. I found once that if I enabled FN keys using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080873/4889030) and then restarted IntelliJ and enabled FN keys using my answer, the "osascript" popup appeared. Are you getting the osascript popup?